A formal inquiry of geometric-problem solving
Let $\Lambda$ be a finite set. Let $\mathcal{L}$ be a finite collection of lines on a plane $X$. Then, define $X^*(\mathcal{L}) = \bigcup_{L_\alpha\neq L_\beta}  L_{\alpha}\cap L_{\beta}$ to be the set of all points of intersection of the lines in $\mathcal{L}$ on the two-dimensional plane.
Let $E \subseteq X$ be a finite subset of points in the plane. Then, define $\mathcal{L}^*(E) = \{L(x,y) : x\neq y ; x,y\in X\}$, where $L(x,y)$ is the line joining $x$ and $y$, to be the set of all possible lines generated from the set $E$.
Let an angle emanating between $L_1$ and $L_2$ be called $Q_j(L_1,L_2) \in [0,360]$, $L_1\neq L_2$ where the index $j\in \{0,1\}$ defines one of the two angles.
Let $\phi^*(\mathcal{L}) := \mathcal{L}^*(X^*(\mathcal{L}))$ be the operator that maps finite sets of lines to finite sets of lines by the above operations.
i) Does the sequence of compositions $\{\phi^{*k}(\mathcal{L})\}_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ converge in a finite number of steps i.e. is it eventually constant?
ii) Suppose we are given the angles $Q_j(L_1,L_2), L_1\neq L_2; L_1,L_2\in \mathcal{L};j \in \{0,1\}$ on the plane. Then, suppose we have an additive (over adjacent angles on the plane) extension $\hat{Q}_j(L_1,L_2)\in [0,360], L_1\neq L_2; L_1,L_2\in \mathcal{L}^*(X^*(\mathcal{L}));j \in \{0,1\}$ of $Q$ such that for each polygon $\{L_1,L_2,....,L_n\} \subseteq \mathcal{L}^*(X^*(\mathcal{L}))$ with corresponding angles denoted by $(j_1,j_2,....,j_n)$, we have that $Q_{j_n}(L_n,L_1) + \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}Q_{j_k}(L_k,L_{k+1})  =180n - 360$.
Then, is it true that $\hat{Q}_j(L_1,L_2) = Q_j(L_1,L_2)$? In other words, by applying the constraint that all angles in a polygon sum to a given constant, is it possible to obtain the angles generated on the plane?

The answer to (i) is no. If you start with a regular hexagon, then after one step you have a finite set that includes a larger regular hexagon. So this grows indefinitely. This probably means the answer to (ii) is also no.

Notice the typographical difference between these two lines: $$ \begin{align} & \text{$X^(\mathcal{L}) = \cup_{L_\alpha\neq L_\beta}  L_\alpha \cap L_\beta$} \ {} \ & \textstyle{X^(\mathcal{L}) = \bigcup_{L_\alpha\neq L_\beta}  L_\alpha \cap L_\beta} \end{align} $$ My edit changed the former to the latter.

Thanks @DaveBenson! i) For 3 or 4 lines, we will get either a triangle or a quadrilateral. In the case of a triangle, there would be no new lines. The quadrilateral would have diagonals, which if we join, then next step onwards, we have a constant sequence. Could you give a simple formal proof of say the more general statement that if the polygonal subdivision created by the lines contains an n-sided polygon, where n is greater than or equal to 5, then that polygon would have infinite subdivisions, taking the union $\bigcup_{k}\phi^{*k}(\mathcal{L})$?

@DaveBenson Is $cl(\bigcup_{k}\phi{^*}(\mathcal{L})) = X$? ii) If the polygonal subdivision contains a quadrilateral, then joining the diagonals, the polygonal constraints would not allow geometric-problem solving, for finding the new angles. One may show this for n-sided polygons, $n\geq 5$. Of course, here we are only allowed to use a ruler and no compass. Hence, no insights (rules) involving parallel lines, perpendiculars or circles. One may hence note that if the geometric problem is defined by lines and angles, then with a ruler alone, one may not generically be able to get the angles.

@MichaelHardy Thanks!
